# Does Stack Overflow contradict itself often?

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php?rq=1) couple of days ago and it is bothering me. Regarding this passage:

> **Why is this?**
>
> Questions like "Headers already sent" or "Calling a member of a
>   non-object" pop up frequently on Stack Overflow. The root cause of
>   those questions is always the same. So the answers to those questions
>   typically repeat them and then **show the OP which line to change in
>   his/her particular case. These answers do not add any value to the
>   site because they only apply to the OP's particular code.**

I get the intention of the post, I also get the unhelpful and repetetive answers clogging the minds of other users with same problem/issue as OP. But this line:

> These answers do not add any value to the site because they only apply to the OP's particular code.

Huh?! I came across numerous comments like "answer is too generic", "your answer is not precise enough", "doesn't apply to OP's situation" and the most commonly found "That was not OP's original question". (I mean one can argue that those people may have missed **EDIT**s on those questions, but still.)

If Stack Overflow is **not** about answers that **only apply to the OP's particular code**, then how can someone benefit from precise answers?

To clarify what I mean regarding "Contradiction" i.e what is the "Contradiction"? It is this: "The Answer should be scenario-specific so as to help the OP vs. Instead of solving OP's problem by a non-generic/too-localized answer helpful for a particular case, add an answer that targets future user". I see a contradiction in this because this doesn't really help the OP, who is the one who started the whole thread in the first place, which I think was why people needed SO in the first place. (SO has a different process for creating docs/adding helpful reference and explanatory answers, not in the scope of my claim. I am talking only about the regular SO questions, which I regularly use search engines to find.)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where do you see the contradiction? Who do you mean by "Stack Overflow"? This is a community of users with many members, so individual opinions are bound to contradict each other with some frequency.

Comment: @yivi May be you didn't check my link. A community wiki answer is not subject to an **individual opinion.**  And of course I meant the community, as far as I know, there is no guardians other than moderators in SO that you run towards crying.

Comment: Different people contradict each other. That's normal. The best thing is probably somewhere in the middle, a compromise of abstract and specific.

Comment: Not much of a discussion if you accept an answer like 18 minutes after you post the question ;)

Comment: @Gimby This was getting wrong attentions, as you can see in previous comments. I honestly believe *SO does contradict and doesn't really follow its goals to the letter.* Its better to ask and proven wrong.

Comment: I had an answer in the works but scraped it, the essence of it was this: Answers should be specific to the question *but* questions should be on-topic. They both work in sync. When both conditions are met, not only is a quality Q&A library built but the questioners question is resolved too. So, no, I don't think there is any contradiction here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that the two statements contradict each other (unless posted under the same answer :) )
There are two extremes:

- Answers that are only solving OPs problem but can not be generalized to similar problems. For example, answering a question about a specific error code with "Change line X to code Y" is not really helpful for others as they would have to find out what the underlying cause is before they can apply the answer to their own problem.
- Answers that are that much generic that they don't help OP at all. When, for example, the same question as above is answered with a list of the 25 most common reasons for this error code without any sign which of the cases apply to OPs problem, then it is also not really helpful

In general, you should try to answer questions in a way that both needs are fulfilled: The answer should contain enough general information to be useful to future readers with similar problems, but it should still help OP to solve their problem.

Comment: *In general, you should try to answer questions in a way that both needs are fulfilled: The answer **should contain enough general information to be useful to future readers with similar problems, but it should still help OP to solve their problem.*** I think you outline my point better. It should be so that OP gets higher priority.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin: No, I don't think that op should get a higher priority. In fact, it should be the opposite. The goal of SO is to build a high quality library of good questions and answers. Helping op is part of the story, but more a by-product of writing good answers then the main motivation.

Comment: As I was working, I went through my upvoted answers just to make sure what makes good answers that helped me so that I can come back to them in future. I don't really assume to know every users' intention of using SO, but are you saying people should not expect scenario specific answers when they come across something they are stuck with?

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin Imho, you have to find a good way to care for both groups: You have to be helpful to op, but you also have to keep in mind how your answer can help future visitors. See it a bit selfish: OP can give you one up-vote. If you want to have 100 upvotes for your question, then op is only 1%. The other 99% come from visitors who have a similar problem and find your answer also applicable to their problem.

Comment: Yes but that can also mean they searched for the exact same thing, rather than a problem in that area which helped them debug because the answer also covers their problem. A good answer may just mean it is spot-on. In any event, I feel like this was a good waste of everyone's time, as indicated by down vote in the question.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin I don't think that your question was a waste of time. This discrepancy between [what SO strives for](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and what askers want is one of the major conflict fields of this site. Please note, that votes on meta do not affect your reputation.

Answer (score 7):

> If Stack overflow is not about answers that only apply to the OP's particular code, then how can someone benefit from precise answers?

Questions and answers in Stack Overflow are meant to help future visitors. That's much more important than helping the specific asker. We are building a "[a library of detailed answers to every question about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)", and that library is meant for future visitors looking for answers.

That one specific asker gets help is very nice, and a **desired side-effect**, but if a question and answer only help that specific asker and it is not useful for future visitors, then it's not really useful for the site.

> I came across numerous comments like "answer is too generic", "your answer is not precise enough", "doesn't apply to OP's situation" and the most commonly found "That was not OP's original question". (I mean one can argue that those people may have missed EDITs on those questions, but still.)

Sometimes users will not understand a duplicate and will demand that a specific answer is provided for them. More often than not, the situation should be resolved in comments at most, and a new answer covering the Nth variation of the same problem would not benefit anyone but the asker.

And the asker **would only benefit in the very short term**: they would get their code fixed by someone else (yay! free work!), but would fail to learn to address their problem properly.

The latter is more desirable for the asker, and a better use of this site.

Comment: You are adding your own opinions about SO as answers. `Questions and answers in Stack Overflow are meant to help future visitors. That's much more important than helping the specific asker.` Where did you find this? May be add Comments instead of answering

Comment: Nice description of an intrinsic conflict. Those who ask questions want answers to their questions, those who answer question may want something different (like writing an encyclopedia).

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin It's all around on the site. It's the reason we have "typo" as a close reason, or for having canonicals as the one you linked. You can argue against it, but the [goal of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is _"to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."_ which is logically meant for future visitors. Both askers and answerers work together towards this goal.

Comment: @yivi Completely disagree and you sound almost like an author of a Book you want everyone to read rather than a contributor. You said and I quote: *That one specific asker gets help is very nice, and a desired side-effect,..* I am sorry why would any one post in here other than a specific situation? I spend years coming here searching very specific strings in search engines not for a **a desired side-effect,**.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin You may not like it, but that's the aim of the site. The whole plan is to use the energy of users that need help and users who want to provide help to build this library. And it works. Usually you can find the solution to your troubles in SO **withouth having to ask a question**, because the library was already there.

Comment: @yivi You are not quoting SO, but probably your own opinion. So don't really know how you, just one person, can state **but that's the aim of the site, The whole plan etc.** Instead of using these term may be use words that are suggestive not definitive.

Comment: @Mohammad, it's straight from the tour. I'm not making this up. If you read around on the help center and in meta, you'll see that this is not just my opinion, but that this is really the aim of the site.

Comment: @yivi I am not really sure how you can benefit from a **"library was already there"**. I know it is. I am stuck. The whole point I am here is because I am not incompetent, (which I think you are suggesting something implicitly inferred by anyone asking questions), I am just stuck. And I need help from people proficient in that lib.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin I have no clue why do you think I believe you are incompetent. I have no idea who you are or your level of competency, and I wouldn't make any claim about it. At no point I implied anything of the sort and I resent the accusation.

Comment: @yivi Sorry let me clarify, I meant anyone asking a specific question requesting a specific answer, not a generic one. Not just me. You aren't claiming anything, you are just labeling a request for scenario-specific answers as side effect and I quote you `And the asker would only benefit in the very short term: they would get their code fixed by someone else (yay! free work!), but would fail to learn to address their problem properly.` Sorry that doesn't seem like you are respectful to the asker

Comment: This is getting too long, and I'm failing at making myself understood. I believe you are misreading me, and I can't help you. I meant no disrespect to anyone, I was just trying to describe you how the site is supposed to work. This is my informed interpretation of the site aims and rules. I believe you got the impression there is some "contradiction" because you didn't proprerly understand those. I was trying to help you see **why** there is no contradiction, but apparently I'm failing. I'm out. Peace.

Comment: @yivi I think the one thing people even use Stack Overflow was to get somewhere with their problems, and this 'future user can be benefited too or whatever ' thing is ambiguous and over-ambitious. You can't really expect to create a curated place for programming knowledge and practices with that in mind, you are also straying from specificity. Peace.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin: "The goal of Stack Exchange is not to construct un-findable single-serving questions that only help one person, but that’s exactly what guessing game questions tend to do." -- [Jeff Atwood, cofounder, in 2012, explaining why a particular type of question is a bad fit for the existing site vision](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/). SO has worked toward the goal you describe as "ambiguous and over-ambitious" from the beginning. "You can't really expect to create a curated place for programming knowledge …" but we actually have.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin Most other programming Q/A sites out there subscribe to the model you seem to be expecting here.  Most others sites exist to simply provide a place for people to ask questions, people to answer the question for that one asker, and for that question to never be seen again by anyone else.  The founders of this site found that model to be problematic, and decided to make a place that was different.  But fortunately for you, if you want to participate in a site that assumes questions only exist to help one person, most every other Q/A site out there is for you.

Comment: There is no other Q/A sites out there which I'm interested in. And people who are acting all elitist claiming to know SO's goal over and over again, I ask you, did you even post an answer here which you wrote with a plan to help more than one people? This is the problem with 2019, everyone who knows little something act like they know what they are talking about. No one posts an answer thinking about future readers while writing the answet, yet they cry havoc that's what this is about.

Comment: I don't know who you are addressing with this comment, @Mohammad, but I **did post an answer useful for future visitors**. And maybe you should think that if so many users are telling you the same thing about the goals of the site, it's you the one who hasn't completely grasped it yet. It's not "elitist" in any way trying to help other users.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin (calling people elitist and claiming that they "know little" appears to be unkind)